# Jmeter no longer loads txt file from directory

Tags: jmeter

I have Jmeter installed with homebrew. I have a text plan that has been working fine and which I saved before rebooting. Upon rebooting my machine and reloading the test plan, I keep getting "File not found exceptions" even though everything is in the same location and nothing about the test plan has changed.

How do I make jmeter go to a specific directory and look for a file? Help.

Comment: Did you launch jmeter from the same folder (e.g. launching it as `./jmeter` may be different from `/full/path/to/jmeter`)? and by the same user? are you using any relative paths?

Comment: Awesome! Didn't think of that! Thanks a lot! - Answer it so I can upvote you. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your text file should be in the **same** directory from where you have launched your JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Given you installed via Homebrew JMeter's working directory depends on where you launch JMeter from. You can check it in i.e. *jmeter.log* file

```
2016/05/09 06:40:50 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/private/tmp
2016/05/09 06:40:50 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/private/tmp
```

So you have 3 options:

1. Start Jmeter from the folder where files live
2. Move files to the folder where JMeter is running from now
3. The best one: use full paths instead of relative. Actually this is what is recommended in [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article.